# Why my application crashes when I put the value for android:ems in dimens.xml?

Tags: android, ems

I'm starting with Android, and I'm trying to put all my dimensions in dimens.xml. I tried the same approach for `android:ems`, but it causes the app to crash.

I thought that I could use dimens resources for ems values. By this way I could have all the ems' values together in the same file.

Here's the layout code:

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textContact"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:ems="@dimen/act_cont_editName_ems">
            <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>
```

And here's the code in dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="act_cont_editName_ems">14</dimen>
```

However, the app only runs properly when I use `android:ems="14"`

I suppose dimens resource file are for dp and sp values only, not sure. If so, is there another way I can keep all ems values in a resource file?

Comment: And here's the code in dimens.xml :
'<dimen name="act_cont_editName_ems">14</dimen>

Answer (score 2):

All dimensions configured in the dimens.xml must have units, and there are six supported units in the dimens.xml.

Commonly used units are sp (scale-independent pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), px (pixels pixels), in addition to support in (inches), mm (millimeters) and pt (points at 72 DPI).

To reference the above defined dimens in xml, you can use @dimen/sizeA.
To reference the above defined dimens in your code, you can use 
`getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sizeB);`

However, in the layout, you will often use some constant values ​​without units, such as setting the weight value of each children in the LinearLayout (android: layout_weight), and setting the line spacing multiple (android: lineSpacingMultiplier) in the TextView. These values ​​cannot be saved in the dimens.xml by means of a direct definition as follows without a unit.

```
<dimen name="sizeD">18</dimen>
<dimen name="sizeE">5.5</dimen>
```

Save the value without unit in dimens.xml

To save a value without a unit in dimensions.xml, you can define it in the following format.

```
<item name="text_line_spacing" type="dimen" format="float">1.2</item>
```

Comment: this answer should be accepted because it is valid

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions can't read value without special attribute. Read more here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Dimension

You can keep ems value in xml